# kinetic js query text align ment is not good enough to my requirement

Tags: kineticjs

var text = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 10,
  y: 15,
  text: 'Simple Text',
  fontsize: 30,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'green'
});

i want my text to end at 10,15 irrespective to starting position same y position is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You can right-align your test using the Kinetic.Text `align` property:

```
new Kinetic.Text({ 
    x: 10, y: 15, text: 'Simple Text', fontsize: 30, 
    fontFamily: 'Calibri', fill: 'green', align:'right' });
```